# showing items when 'x' is present

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok, so hoping I can get some help here after searching with no joy.

So I have a key 'orderno' and each 'orderno' has multiple items.  Each item has a status.  I want to pull a Q that shows only the orderno's that contain an item that has status of 'x'

So If there are 3 items and only 1 is showing status 'x' I want to see all three items not just the one.

Essentially removing any order/items that do not show the x value.

So table1

```
orderno / Itemno / Itemstatus
1           1          y
1           2          x
2           1          z
3           1          y
3           2          x
3           3          y
4           1          y
4           1          y
```

EDIT:

So basically the letters represent open, closed, or inprogress... I want to see only order that have and item closed as well as an item in progress so I can see why the order is only showing partially complete from there.  Still probably not making sense here. Grrrr.

I need to return the ORDER# and all item#'s for any order that contains an item with status of 'x'.

Comment: edited the original statement

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Order_Table
WHERE orderno IN
(SELECT orderno FROM Order_Table WHERE Itemstatus = 'x')
```

The Inner query returns all the orders with the status `'x'` and the outer one return all details of those orders.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer EXISTS to the IN or JOIN versions. It general faster.

Added a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8946d/1/0).

```
CREATE TABLE table1(orderno INT, Itemno INT, Itemstatus CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
 (1,1,'y')
,(1,2,'x')
,(2,1,'z')
,(3,1,'y')
,(3,2,'x')
,(3,3,'y')
,(4,1,'y')
,(4,1,'y')

SELECT *
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM table1 b 
               WHERE b.OrderNo = a.OrderNo 
                 AND b.Itemstatus='x')
```